# File not showing express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in nodejs,Just installed nodejs and express.js using command and i will get folder like node modules so i just want to know is this right way or there should some other folder also or there is some other way for install nodejs and express.js

Comment: yes, this is the right way. You would get a directory named `node_modules` in the root of your project.

Comment: You may use https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html to get started, node_modules folder will be automatically created when you install dependencies

Comment: @vibhor1997a : is express.js based on mvc ? if yes then how we can post values from views to controller ?

Comment: @ArifKhan : in  link which you mentioned , i have to use " npm install express-generator -g " command for get full directory/folder ?

Comment: @ShikhaBansal read documentation, you need to run above command and then restart command line if you are using Windows and then run `express projectName`  that is `express` command added

Comment: @ArifKhan : Thank you so much it worked for me , but how can i post form data view to controller ?

Comment: @ShikhaBansal If you want the demo project node and express architecture with api routes, you can check it  from: 
`https://github.com/radhey113/node-with-express-and-swagger`